# Couldn't import a python file between sibling Sub-folders

Tags: python

My file structure looks like this:

```
subFolder1
|___   __init__.py
|___   first.py

subFolder2
|___   __init__.py
|___   second.py
```

When I import the **first.py** from the **second.py** using the command `from subFolder1.first import MyClass`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subFolder1'`.

I have seen many questions regarding this, everyone say python doesn't know the path.
If so, then how does this [image: code] from django works ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Does your init.py import first.py? I think you need to add '..' to path (parent dir).

Comment: When you run `second.py` directly `subFolder2` is going to become your import base folder (aka `PYTHONPATH`). It is advisable that you put the module that is executed at the top level of your project.

Comment: @likethevegetable Python 3.8.1 and yes I did import it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main script has to reside outside both packages in order for the import to work the way you have it right now.

You have to add the following lines to `second.py` file if you want to run `second.py` and import `subFolder1` package.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

The reason it works in the Django example is as follows (in laymen terms):

```
TopLevelFolder
|___run.py
|___subFolder1
    |___   __init__.py
    |___   first.py

    subFolder2
    |___   __init__.py
    |___   second.py
```

The imports are done in `run.py`. So if you do `from subFolder1.first import MyClass` and then import `SubFolder2.second` into `run.py` and run the code form there your import will work the way you have it right now.

Comment: Thank you so much. As you said, there must be a `run.py` file there I guess.